# Changing image source in HTML from PHP called through script?

Tags: php, html

Currently, I have a button in my HTML file that calls the following script:

```
 <script>
        function myFunction(textToUpdate)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                  document.getElementById(textToUpdate).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","myPhp.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

... where textToUpdate is implemented as follows:

```
<p style="font-family:helvetica;"><span id="textToUpdate"></span></p>
```

Then, in myPhp.php, I do a few server-side operations to generate a string, which I echo directly into textToUpdate. This works great! But I'd like to do a little more from myPhp.php, such as changing an image. I can do that just fine from the HTML file itself ...

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');
img.src = 'newImage.jpg';
```

But I'm having trouble doing this from the php. I attempted to pass 'image' instead of textToUpdate in the script, and then doing the following from myPhp.php ....

```
echo img.src = 'newImage.jpg';
```

But nothing happens.

So, is it possible to do something like this? Or can I only echo text strings to paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
echo "<img src='newImage.jpg' />";
```

or say if you have this `newImage.jpg` in a variable like this below..

```
$img='newImage.jpg';
echo "<img src=$img />";
```

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't quite seem to work. Might the issue be with my code in the script, "document.getElementById(textToUpdate).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText"? Specifically, the xml.http.responseText part? I'm guessing that needs to be something different to actually execute the <img src='newImage.jpg'/> line ...